# Binary array in python

Tags: python

How to create big array in python, how efficient creating that

in C/C++:

```
byte *data = (byte*)memalloc(10000);
```

or

```
byte *data = new byte[10000];
```

in python...?

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the [array module](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html):

```
import array
array.array('B', [0] * 10000)
```

Instead of passing a list to initialize it, you can pass a generator, which is more memory efficient.

Comment: The fastest array initialization is **`array.array('B', [0]) * 10000`**. (i.e. mupliplied short array) see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3214343/448474

Answer (score 6):

You can pre-allocate a list with:

```
l = [0] * 10000
```

which will be slightly faster than .appending to it (as it avoids intermediate reallocations).  However, this will generally allocate space for a list of pointers to integer objects, which will be larger than an array of bytes in C.

If you need memory efficiency, you could use an array object.  ie:

```
import array, itertools
a = array.array('b', itertools.repeat(0, 10000))
```

Note that these may be slightly slower to use in practice, as there is an unboxing process when accessing elements (they must first be converted to a python `int` object).

Comment: 'B' must be used (for unsigned char) not 'b', because the former is the only one that C guarantees is a type that has all bits contributing to it's value.

Answer (score 0):

Typically with python, you'd just create a list

```
mylist = []
```

and use it as an array.  Alternatively, I think you might be looking for the array module.  See http://docs.python.org/library/array.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can efficiently create big array with **array** module, but using it won't be as fast as C. If you intend to do some math, you'd be better off with **numpy.array**

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111983/python-array-versus-numpy-array) for comparison.