# How to send and receive large numpy arrays (several GBs) using flask

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask, python-requests, protocol-buffers

I am creating a micro-service to be used locally. From some input I am generating one large matrix each time. Right now I am using json to transfer the data but it is really slow and became the bottleneck of my application.

Here is my client side:

```
headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

data = {'model': 'model_4', \
        'input': "this is my input."}

r = requests.post("http://10.0.1.6:3000/api/getFeatureMatrix", headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))

answer = json.loads(r.text)
```

My server is something like:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='public')

@app.route('/api/getFeatureMatrix', methods = ['POST'])
def get_feature_matrix():
    arguments = request.get_json()
    #processing ... generating matrix
    return jsonify(matrix=matrix.tolist())
```

How can I send large matrices ?

Comment: What about send the data as binary?

Comment: Any idea of how I can do this ? How can I transform my matrix to binary and how can I receive it properly on the other end?

Comment: You can check python `array` module or `numpy`. Here is a question related with it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751055/binary-array-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I ended up using

```
np.save(matrix_path, mat)
return send_file(matrix_path+'.npy')
```

On the client side I save the matrix before loading it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the problem is that the matrix takes time to generate. It's a CPU bound application

One solution would be to handle the request asynchronously. Meaning that:

1. The server receives request and returns a 202 ACCEPTED and the link to where the client can check the progress of the creation of the matrix
2. The client checks the returned url he either gets:

   - a 200 OK response if the matrix is not yet created
   - a 201 CREATED response if the matrix is finally created, with a link to the resource

However, Flask handles one request at a time. So you'll need to use multithreading or multiprocessing or greenthreads.

Answer (score 0):

On the client side you could do something like:

```
 with open('binariy.file', 'rb') as f:
     file = f.read()
     response = requests.post('/endpoint', data=file)
```

and on the Server side:

```
import numpy as np

...

@app.route('/endpoint', methods=['POST'])
def endpoint():
    filestr = request.data
    file = np.fromstring(filestr)
```